# Get the minimum value of passenger

Tags: normal-distribution

I have this statement:

> The luggage weight of a commercial aircraft follows normal distribution $W(Weight) \sim N(20kg,4kg)$
>   .If the limit of The total luggage load of an aircraft carrying $100$
>   passengers is $2092.8kg$, So what is the probability that the limit is
>   exceeded by these $100$ passengers?

My attempt was:

Assuming that each passenger will exceed the weight of their luggage by the same amount, then each passenger will exceed: $2092.8/100 = 20.928$

Thus, i need $P( W > 20.928) = k$

Normalize, $P(Z > 0.232) = 0.4083$

But the correct answer must be $0.01$, that is $1 - P(Z < 2.32)$, where $P(Z < 2.32) \approx 0.99$ And i don't know how to get this.

So, what is wrong in my attempt? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to find is the probability that the total weight of $100$ pieces of luggage, each of which independently has weight from a normal distribution with mean $20$ and standard deviation $4$, exceeds $2092.8$. Equivalently, you need to know the probability that the sample mean of a random sample of $100$ bags from the normal distribution $N(20,4)$ exceeds $209.28$. (It is not necessary for each of the $100$ bags to be above average in weight.) If you are at the point in your study where you’re expected to solve this problem, you should already be aware of the relationship between a distribution (the weights of bags) and the sampling distribution (the distribution of the means of samples of a given size) from that distribution.

Comment: You mean to get a sample of $100$ and use the relationship $\sim  N(\mu, \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})$? And why need exceds $209.28$?

Comment: The sample mean might exceed $20.928$.

Comment: Yes, the distribution of sample means is $N(\mu, \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})$, and you need to find the probability that for $n=100, \mu=20, \sigma=4$ a value chosen from that distribution exceeds 20.928.

Comment: That need exceeds $20.928$ because is equal to say "in average, the weight must exceeds 20.928" and that average is represented by the mean of the sample, is my thought correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use X as the sum of 100 iid normals, so X~N(2000kg,400kg). Then use X for the calculation. If the 4kg is the standard deviation, the Var(X) = 100(4^2) =1600 and X ~ N(2000 kg, 40 kg). This gets the correct answer.

Comment: Your assumption that each passenger will exceed by an equal amount excludes the many numerous ways in which the amount by which each passenger exceeds their allowance varies and yet produce an overall excess of 2092.8 kg.

Comment: This produce the same result.

Comment: No it doesn’t. I see a misunderstanding in the variance/standard deviation. The 4kg seems to be standard deviation for you whereas I have used it as the variance. In that case, X ~ N(2000 kg, 40 kg) . Now, P(X > 2092.8) = P[Z > (92.8/40)] = 0.010170... and that’s it.

Comment: $4kg$ isn't the variance, $4kg$ is the standar deviation according to my question

Comment: Then X ~ N(2000 kg, 40 kg) gets the result.

Comment: Can you explain me, how you get that variance? is unclear for me

Comment: Each passenger’s luggage weight (actually, this is mass since we are using kg) has variance 4^2 =16, that’s variance is the square of standard deviation. since X is the sum of 100 independent RVs of this distribution, X has variance 100(16) = 1600 and standard deviation sqrt(1600) =40.

Comment: why the variance is $100(16)$? If u set $U = X + X + .... + X = 100X$ , thus the variance of $100X$ is equal to $V(100X) = 100^2 \cdot 16 = 160000 $

Comment: The problem is that U = X + X + ....+ X  is not equal to 100X. The second is 100 times a single RV, ie, 100 times the same RV. The first is the sum of 100 iid RVs. Please note that if X and Y are iid RVs, it does not follow that X = Y. Independent and identically distributed (iid) does not mean the Xs are the same, so you can’t equate their sum to 100 times one of them.

Comment: What you want to do is Var(U) = Var ( X +...+ X) = Var(X) + ...+ Var(X) = 100 Var(X) = 100(16). I have used the fact that the iids are independent so their covariances are zero.l and the variance of their sum is the sum of their variances.

Comment: how you know that are independent?